# Publishing website changes to a ruby server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I am in the midst of remaking a site using a new CMS install that currently lives on a Ruby (Ubuntu & Puma - According to the original DEV) setup. Before the new site is launched they wanted to make a few textual and image updates to the current live site.

I was given an ssh to connect to the remote server and make the requested changes however I am unable to publish those changes to the live site. I'm certain that this is due to my complete lack of knowledge regarding how Ruby works.

I've done some research and came across a few resources the primary one of use directly below:

1. [GitHub.com/puma/puma](https://github.com/puma/puma)

After looking into this option I tried the following to make the changes reflect on the live site.

1. Restarted Puma
2. Restarted NGinX
3. Restarted HTTP on the AWS it's living in.
4. Creation/touch of a restart.txt file in the temporary directory

Sadly none of these changes published my updates. I've found plenty of articles on the initial deployment of Ruby servers, however, nothing in them gave me an indication about publishing changes, or if it did my lacking knowledge base about the language cause me to miss it.

Would anyone out there be able to suggest a standard process for publishing changes I'm not coming across or need clarification on?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
Turns out I was able to get ahold of the original DEV. He left me some instructions which are as follows:

1. Please make the image/html changes in the required files.
2. Then run the command - `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`
3. Then to kill the running puma process please use these commands -
     `ps aux | grep puma
     kill -9 1025(puma process number)`
4. Then to restart the server use this command - `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`

I did as he said and most everything came up with errors such as:

- rake aborted! No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
- No such process
- And finally upon trying to bundle and execute: `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory` which resulted in the page 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: What is the nature of the changes that you made? Some changes do not even require a restart (changing a view: app/views/videos/index.html.erb) other changes require a restart (changing an initializer) and there are other changes require a restart and specific commands to load (adding a new gem)

Comment: @whodini9 I made two paragraphs of type changes to 3 seperate .html.erb files within my systems app folder and uploaded 1 new image which is being used in two separate places. That's it.

Comment: Can you add the paths to the files you changed/added?

Comment: In the server the files update are located under: app/views/home and app/views/static_pages. As for the image, it's under: assets/images/banner.

Comment: Noticed this at the top: *** System restart required *** think this could hold things up?

Comment: Updates made, see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the dev's instructions turned out to be the correct method of update, he just forgot to state the folder level at which I was to run them. I ran them at the root level he'd provided me rather than 3 directories down where he housed the site folder. Here are the steps below without any error info from the above question:

1. Run the command - RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
2. Then to kill the running PUMA process please use these commands:
     ps aux | grep puma
     kill -9 1025(puma process number)
3. Then to restart the server use this command: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb

Once these commands were applied to the dev specified folder everything updated as intended. I hope this can help someone else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If you came to already released application, I would expect there would be some automated deployment process. Either [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano), [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/), or maybe some remote git repo with after-commit hooks.

Basically look for `config/deploy.rb` or `config/deploy` directory. Also if you have `Capfile` in your app root, it means that there is an automated deploy set with Capistrano.

Other than that, you didn't write how exactly did you get your changes to the server. If you did it correctly and you got them to the right place, your other steps were correct, if not too much as mentioned by @whodini9.

Comment: Regarding how exactly I made the changes, I opened the specific .html.erb files through the ssh and updated them through there. I double checked just to confirm my updates were honored in the files... looks good. I'm looking for the config file now and will let you know.

Comment: Okay. No luck on the config/deploy.rg or config/deploy. There is a .git directory and .gitignore at the root level of the site though. Would those be what you were highlighting in your comment towards automated process?

Comment: No, it just means the app uses git as a versioning service.

Comment: What was the path of the application at the server? For example Capistrano stores several older deploys so it can be rolled back in case of an error. You could change the backup by accident.

Comment: The files I updated are living under app/views/home and app/views/static_pages

Comment: Yes, but what is the path of the app? Any words such as release, current, backup, restore?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129659/discussion-between-jan-minarik-and-cutter).